# How to check if a database is empty using java

Tags: java, database

I have some functionality which needs the database to be clean, How do i check if my database is clean using JAVA ?
I have already written the code about whether the Database exists or not but I couldn't find any info on how to check if it's clean.

Comment: count the rows in every table? Or just clear the tables in the first place, instead of expecting something else to do it beforehand.

Comment: depends on the database that you use, there are queries that you can get all table names. then iterate that result and execute select (only get the rowcount) for each and every table.

Comment: that is one way to do it , but my DB has over 100 tables so i am not sure if it is the right way to do it ? also I should thrown an exception if the DB is not empty so cleaning the table is not an option

Comment: Your request that the database must be empty is a little weird but this is something you need to solve yourself since there is no general solution for it. Maybe you don't need to check all table but only a few key ones?

Comment: @RajieRoo There's no other way... In any case even for 100 tables it should be fast with `count()`.

Comment: I guess that is the only option left then.

Comment: What is your database? you can run a procedure to check the emptiness of all existing tables. for example, you can get the list of tables in oracle using `all_tables` table.

Comment: Right now my database is MSSQL

Answer (score -1):

take a look at that code:

```
public static void createLocalDB(String driver, String url, String user, String password) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement;

    try {
        connection = SQLUtils.getDBConnection(driver,url,user,password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS INTERACTION_SEQ;");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS interaction(id CHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,sequence BIGINT DEFAULT INTERACTION_SEQ.NEXTVAL,type CHAR(20),startdate TIMESTAMP,enddate TIMESTAMP,timeshift INT DEFAULT 0,xml CLOB, finished BOOLEAN DEFAULT false);");
        statement.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS date_index_interaction ON interaction(startdate);");
        statement.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS seq_index_interaction ON interaction(sequence);");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Error creating new local db, message:{}",e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if( connection != null ) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this method can be used by you in your project, the aim of the method is to create the database if that is empty (do not exist). Just adapt the queries for your database tables, and it will be able to generate sequences, tables, etc. Notice that my SQL syntax is for H2 database, then you need to adapt to your own.

If you have any further question just let me know, I hope to help you out with that,

Cheers,

-Rod